# Given input voltage and a set of output voltages of a second order low pass filter, how to calculate the gain of the filter?

Tags: voltage, filter, gain, low-pass

I know that voltage gain = 20 log (Vout/Vin) dB, but the slope of the Bode s plot of second order low pass filter is -40dB/decade compared to the first order low pass filter with -20dB/decade. So should the voltage gain formula be 40 log(Vout/Vin) or 20 log (Vout/Vin) in case of second order low pass filter?

My input voltage is 0.5v.
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about the calculations you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation of the gain is always the same, so simply 20 log (Vout/Vin). The decibel is simply a tenth of a Bel, so we have 10 dB = 1 B. The factor of 2 comes from the fact that we have a ratio of powers, which is voltages squared. Due to the logarithm the square reduces to a factor of 2.

You should see that you indeed get 40dB drop per decade above the corner frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. 
Then is the cut-off frequency also the same as first order, which is corresponding to -3dB?

Comment: Yes it's 3dB by definition, because 3dB is half the power.

Comment: However, there are some exceptions: It is common practice to define the cut-off frequency for lowpass filters with Chebyshev response (with ripples in the passband) at the end of the "ripple region" (for example: 0.1 dB, 1dB,...).